# boost::shared_ptr is deleted somewhere

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have a simple class structure that uses boost::shared_ptr.

it looks something like -

Point class:

```
boost::shared_ptr<PointPrism> getPrismFromDirection(const Point3& direction) const
{
    return boost::shared_ptr<PointPrism>(new PointPrism(_position, direction));
}

boost::shared_ptr<PointPrism> getPrismFromAimingPoint(const Point3& aimingPoint)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<PointPrism> prism = getPrismFromDirection((aimingPoint - _position).normalized());
    prism->setAimingPoint(aimingPoint);
    return prism;
}
```

Main class:

```
main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Point> p; //initialized somewhere in this code
    boost::shared_ptr<PointPrism> prism = p->getPrismFromAimingPoint(aimingPoint);

    //here it looks like the prism object is just fine
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
    //here both VS10 debugger and log prints show that values inside prism are corrupted
}
```

From what I understand, this means that somewhere in the code the shared_ptr reference count is messed up and a destructor is called, but I can't figure out where.
Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

when breaking at the line `return prism;` at pressing Alt+Shift+F11 in VS10 (which shows all the function that are going to be called) I see both the boost::shared_ptr ctor and boost::shared_ptr dtor, which (I think) means I am returning the shared_ptr the wrong way. What is wrong there?

Comment: Are you sure those objects are only used with non-owning raw ponters and shared/weak-pointers created from the original shared_pointer or each other, never from raw pointers?

Comment: The code is exactly as described. no pointers/references were dropped here.

Comment: Do you see this behavior if you add another statement after the `boost::this_thread::sleep` call? (For example: add `int i = 0;` as the last line in `main`, and break at it). I'm guessing this is how you logged the values, but I thought I would double check.

Comment: I have some other calls in the main function, including logging the values. No change

Comment: There is nothing wrong with seeing the dtor and ctor for shared_ptr<PointPrism> being called.  You're returning it and it's copy constructing and falling out of scope.  This is normal behavior.  You should attach a breakpoint to ~PointPrism() and see when it's being called.  If it doesn't have a destructor defined, then define one and do it.

Comment: The ~PointPrism is called only at the end of this main() block. Does that mean that I have a memory corruption? That will be highly odd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out it was a bug (not mine... *wicked smile*) in a whole different place.
The members of the `PointPrism` class were saved as const reference, which made them delete outside the method that creates them...
Thanks everyone for the help.